# MFC change mouse cursor on hover over CEdit control

Tags: mfc, hover, cursor, cedit, custom-cursor

I want to change mouse cursor to custom cursor which i added to project Resource named IDC_MY_CURSOR. i want to change mouse pointer to my cursor whenever mouse is over CEdit control only. Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To override the default behavior of standard controls, you will have to provide your own implementation. The most straight forward way to do this using MFC is to derive from a standard control implementation ([CEdit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7yhsd2b.aspx) in this case):

*CustomEdit.h:*

```
class CCustomEdit : public CEdit {
public:
    CCustomEdit() {}
    virtual ~CCustomEdit() {}

protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()

public:
    // Custom message handler for WM_SETCURSOR
    afx_msg BOOL OnSetCursor( CWnd* pWnd, UINT nHitTest, UINT message );
};
```

*CustomEdit.cpp:*

```
#include "CustomEdit.h"

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP( CCustomEdit, CEdit )
    ON_WM_SETCURSOR()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

BOOL CCustomEdit::OnSetCursor( CWnd* pWnd, UINT nHitTest, UINT message ) {
    ::SetCursor( AfxGetApp()->LoadCursor( IDC_MY_CURSOR ) );
    // Stop processing
    return TRUE;
}
```

You can use this class to dynamically create a `CCustomEdit` control. Alternatively, you can create a standard edit control (either dynamically or through a resource script), and attach an instance of `CCustomEdit` to it (see [DDX_Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z04ab59a.aspx)):

```
void CMyDialog::DoDataExchange( CDataExchange* pDX ) {
    DDX_Control( pDX, IDC_CUSTOM_EDIT, m_CustomEdit );
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange( pDX );
}
```